# TimePicker not displaying on android 4.4.2 - screenshots attached

Tags: android, dialog, styles, android-4.4-kitkat, timepicker

I have 2 phones, a Nexus 4 with Android 5.0.1, and an LG f60 with Android 4.4.2 on it.

I have a custom dialog with this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" > 
</DatePicker>

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TimePicker>

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View aboveLayout = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.aboveLayout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myDialog.setView(aboveLayout);
...
```

and it displays correctly on Nexus 4, but something is wrong with the `TimePicker` on the LG f60. Here are the screenshot:
[image][image]

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). You can put your pickers under this view. It should fix the problem on small screens. By the way maybe it's better to have 2 dialog for date and for time. It's more conventional and user friendly.

Comment: The problem was the small screen, so you were right, but I do not really want to use scrollview, but sadly we cannot resize TimePicker and DatePicker...